# Use Google Analytics to track users Chatter page visits

Tags: chatter, analytics, google

I have a client that uses the Salesforce platform only for Chatter. I want him to be able to track his users' visits using Google Analytics. The app [Web Analytics](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cuSEAQ), found in the Appexchange, offers the possiblity to do that, but not in Chatter pages, because the module is added in a page as a sidebar component. In the review we  can read : "the component relies on being able to put some JavaScript onto a page which is normally done in the side bar, or dashboard component. Chatter pages do not use the standard side bar so unable to put in the JavaScript to do the page tracking."
Does anyone knows a module, an app, or a customization that does the same thing as Web Analytics but for the Chatter pages?

Thanks a lot,

Karen

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question on this - can we not put the google tracking code inside the chatter group in the description or information sections? They always appear. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if [GoodData Community Analytics for Chatter](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4Vp7EAF) will at all do what you desire. According to the [Press Release on GoodData's web site](http://www.gooddata.com/in-the-news/gooddata-launches-four-new-apps-on-salesforce-appexchange), they offer a 30 day free trial and had the following to say about it:

> - Measure the adoption, engagement and overall success of Chatter
>     Communities.
> - Identify and cultivate community influencers and
>     contributors to stay in tune with customer and employee needs.
> - Determine trending keywords, topics and files with sentiment and
>     emotionality analysis, which provides additional context across
>     groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, crmprogdev. I'm waiting for GoodData to have a trial of their solution